# Call method in main class from instantiated object

Tags: java, android

What I am trying to do is this:

```
public class MainClass {
    private UIController uIController;

    MainClass() {
        uIController = new UIController();
    }

    public void MethodIWantToCall() {
        //Do Something
    }
}
```

UIController Class example:

```
public class UIController {
    UIController() {
        //Call a method in MainClass here, for example MethodIWantToCall()
    }

    public void MethodA {
        //Call a method in MainClass here, for example MethodIWantToCall()
    }
}
```

What I want to do is that UIController pass to MainClass commands, calling its methods or return value to MainClass as the user interacts with the UI.

Comment: Sounds weird. Looks like a delegate pattern to me.

Comment: unrelated, but: `public void MethodA {` should be `public void MethodA() {`

Comment: Does `MainClass` extend anything or is it exactly as you have shown in your example code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a reference of a `MainClass` instance to your `UIController` instance, for example:

```
public class UIController {
    private final MainClass mainClass;
    UIController (final MainClass mainClass) {
         this.mainClass = mainClass;
         //Call a method in MainClass here, for example MethodIWantToCall()
         this.mainClass.MethodIWantToCall();
    }

    public void MethodA() {
        //Call a method in MainClass here, for example MethodIWantToCall()
         this.mainClass.MethodIWantToCall();             
    }
}
```

Then

```
uIController = new UIController(this);
```

PS: methods in Java should start with lower-case.

Answer (score -1):

You can make instance field:

```
public class MainClass {
    public static MainClass instance;
    public MainClass() {
        instance=this;
    }
    public void method() {}
}
```

Then, call: MainClass.instance.method(); or:

```
public class MainClass {
    public MainClass() {
        new AnotherClass(this);
    }
    public void method() {}
}
public class AnotherClass {
    public AnotherClass(MainClass main) {
        main.method();
    }
}
```

Comment: Wrong singleton implementation: 1) public constructor and 2) public non-final instance field. What will happen if the constructor is called twice? What will happen if another class modifies `instance`?

Comment: m0skit0 why another class will modify instance? It should be modify only via MainClass.

Comment: Question is why it would not modify it when it is `public`? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28computer_programming%29